# Class Group of the Class Number $3$ with their elements given explicitly

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, class-field-theory

**INTRODUCTION**

The  two-faced behavior of quadratic form $x^2 + 5y^2$  has a hidden companion - the quadratic form $2x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2$ - whose prime values are of the form $20n + 3$ or $20n +7$ (determinant $5$, has two equivalence classes, or class number $2$, irregular behavior).

If we denote the form $x^2 +5y^2$ by $A$ and the form $2x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2$ by $B$, then
Lagrange's results (combined with Brahmagupta's) say that the composites
of $A$ and $B$ have the following "multiplication table":

$$A^2 =A, AB=BA =B, B^2 =A.$$

We recognize this as the multiplication table for the two-element group
with identity element $A$.

Today it is called the class group for $\mathbb Q(\sqrt-5)$.

**WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR:** A list of quadratic forms with their equivalence classes $A, B, C$, i.e. the class group of the class number $3$ with their elements given explicitly.

I came to know that, there are $25$ such quadratic forms from the paper  ["Representation of primes by the principal form of $-D$ when the Class-number $h(- D)$ is $3$"](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/%7Ejagy/Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf). But due to my lacking of technical knowledge in this topic, I can not find the equivalence classes for a specific quadratic form.

probably the following theorem says something about what I am looking -

[image]

***But I can not decode it, can anyone plz decode it for me, in general if there is  list of quadratic forms with their equivalence classes $A, B, C$,in the above paper, can anyone translate that into an elementary way (like the **INTRODUCTION**)? Thanks.***

**EDIT**

1. A deleted answer: The proposition p.132 gives you the list of values of $D$ such that $h(-D)=3$.
   So for each $D$, you have to find the corresponding list of reduced forms.

Now $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ is reduced of discriminant $-D$ if $a,b,c$ are coprime , $|b|\leq a\leq c$ and $b\geq 0\text{ if either }|b|=a\text{ or }a=c$, and of course $b^2-4ac=-D$. The last condition easily implies that $a\leq \sqrt{D/3}$,   so you just have to solve for each value of $D$ by trial and error the finitely many possible values for $a$ abd $b$ (and then $c$)or by programming your favorite CAS.

Comment: Your Table 1 is evidently for *cubics*, not quadratics.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, that confuses me more, could you break down the theorem in simple language and post an answer plz?

Comment: The table on page 51 of https://corentinperretgentil.gitlab.io/static/documents/correspondence-bqf-qf.pdf may help you.

Comment: I don't think that theorem is of any use to you, since it has to do only with a single quadratic form for each $D$, the "principal" form. I don't think it tells you anything about the other equivalence classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A computer algebra system (CAS) like sage delivers the list of representatives immediately.

https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/quadratic_forms/sage/quadratic_forms/binary_qf.html

A short answer would be to use this package.

---

For the reader in hurry, here are the details.
For instance, for the mentioned value $-5$ corresponding to the quadratic field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$, for the investigations of the structure, we would type in sage:

```
A, B = BinaryQF_reduced_representatives(-20)

print(f"A = {A}")
print(f"B = {B}")

print("Is A*A == A? {}".format(A*A == A))
print("Is A*B == B? {}".format(B*A == B))
print("Is B*A == B? {}".format(A*B == B))
print("Is B*B == A? {}".format(B*B == A))

BB = B*B
BB_red = BB.reduced_form()

print(f"Which is the reduced form of B*B = {BB}? It is {BB_red}.")
```

The above code gives as results:

```
A = x^2 + 5*y^2
B = 2*x^2 + 2*x*y + 3*y^2
Is A*A == A? True
Is A*B == B? True
Is B*A == B? True
Is B*B == A? False
Which is the reduced form of B*B = x^2 + 2*x*y + 6*y^2? It is x^2 + 5*y^2.
```

---

At this point a short answer would be to install sage and to ask for the reduced classes in the wanted cases. However, since the code is rather simple, with the risk of filling the whole space of the site...

```
for D in [1..1000]:
    if -D % 4 in [2, 3]:
        continue
    BQFRR = BinaryQF_reduced_representatives(-D, primitive_only=True)
    if len(BQFRR) != 3:
        continue
    A, B, C = BQFRR
    print(f"{-D} & {latex(A)} & {latex(B)} & {latex(C)}\\\\\\hline")
```

(There is no input of the list from the cited reference. Instead, among all discriminants between $-1000$ and $-3$ there is a computed list of representatives, if there are three quadratic forms in the list, we show them.)
The results were copy+pasted inside the following latex array:

$$
\begin{array}{|r||c|c|c|}
\hline
-D & A & B & C\\\hline\hline
-23 & x^{2} + x y + 6 y^{2} & 2 x^{2} - x y + 3 y^{2} & 2 x^{2} + x y + 3 y^{2}\\\hline
-31 & x^{2} + x y + 8 y^{2} & 2 x^{2} - x y + 4 y^{2} & 2 x^{2} + x y + 4 y^{2}\\\hline
-44 & x^{2} + 11 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} - 2 x y + 4 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} + 2 x y + 4 y^{2}\\\hline
-59 & x^{2} + x y + 15 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} - x y + 5 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} + x y + 5 y^{2}\\\hline
-76 & x^{2} + 19 y^{2} & 4 x^{2} - 2 x y + 5 y^{2} & 4 x^{2} + 2 x y + 5 y^{2}\\\hline
-83 & x^{2} + x y + 21 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} - x y + 7 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} + x y + 7 y^{2}\\\hline
-92 & x^{2} + 23 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} - 2 x y + 8 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} + 2 x y + 8 y^{2}\\\hline
-107 & x^{2} + x y + 27 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} - x y + 9 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} + x y + 9 y^{2}\\\hline
-108 & x^{2} + 27 y^{2} & 4 x^{2} - 2 x y + 7 y^{2} & 4 x^{2} + 2 x y + 7 y^{2}\\\hline
-124 & x^{2} + 31 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} - 4 x y + 7 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} + 4 x y + 7 y^{2}\\\hline
-139 & x^{2} + x y + 35 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} - x y + 7 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} + x y + 7 y^{2}\\\hline
-172 & x^{2} + 43 y^{2} & 4 x^{2} - 2 x y + 11 y^{2} & 4 x^{2} + 2 x y + 11 y^{2}\\\hline
-211 & x^{2} + x y + 53 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} - 3 x y + 11 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} + 3 x y + 11 y^{2}\\\hline
-243 & x^{2} + x y + 61 y^{2} & 7 x^{2} - 3 x y + 9 y^{2} & 7 x^{2} + 3 x y + 9 y^{2}\\\hline
-268 & x^{2} + 67 y^{2} & 4 x^{2} - 2 x y + 17 y^{2} & 4 x^{2} + 2 x y + 17 y^{2}\\\hline
-283 & x^{2} + x y + 71 y^{2} & 7 x^{2} - 5 x y + 11 y^{2} & 7 x^{2} + 5 x y + 11 y^{2}\\\hline
-307 & x^{2} + x y + 77 y^{2} & 7 x^{2} - x y + 11 y^{2} & 7 x^{2} + x y + 11 y^{2}\\\hline
-331 & x^{2} + x y + 83 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} - 3 x y + 17 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} + 3 x y + 17 y^{2}\\\hline
-379 & x^{2} + x y + 95 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} - x y + 19 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} + x y + 19 y^{2}\\\hline
-499 & x^{2} + x y + 125 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} - x y + 25 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} + x y + 25 y^{2}\\\hline
-547 & x^{2} + x y + 137 y^{2} & 11 x^{2} - 5 x y + 13 y^{2} & 11 x^{2} + 5 x y + 13 y^{2}\\\hline
-643 & x^{2} + x y + 161 y^{2} & 7 x^{2} - x y + 23 y^{2} & 7 x^{2} + x y + 23 y^{2}\\\hline
-652 & x^{2} + 163 y^{2} & 4 x^{2} - 2 x y + 41 y^{2} & 4 x^{2} + 2 x y + 41 y^{2}\\\hline
-883 & x^{2} + x y + 221 y^{2} & 13 x^{2} - x y + 17 y^{2} & 13 x^{2} + x y + 17 y^{2}\\\hline
-907 & x^{2} + x y + 227 y^{2} & 13 x^{2} - 9 x y + 19 y^{2} & 13 x^{2} + 9 x y + 19 y^{2}\\\hline
\end{array}
$$

The computations in sage
are giving a clear pattern.

- In case $-D=-4d$, $d$ positive integer, then
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  A &= x^2 + dy^2\ ,\\
  B &= ax^2 - 2xy +cy^2\ ,\\
  C &= ax^2 + 2xy +cy^2\ ,\\
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  for suitable positive integers $a,c$ with $d=ac-1$.
- In case $-D=-(4d-3)$, $d$ positive integer, then
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  A &= x^2 + xy + dy^2\ ,\\
  B &= ax^2 - bxy +cy^2\ ,\\
  C &= ax^2 + bxy +cy^2\ ,\\
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  for suitable positive integers $a,b,c$ leading to the given discriminant.

---

*Later EDIT:* Here i try to answer the questions in the comment below.
(Please always ask, do not hesitate.)

In the first part, using the quadratic binary forms (qbf) $A=x^2+5y^2$ and $B=2x^2+2xy+3y^2$ sage computes the composition $B\cdot B=x^2+2xy+6y^2$, which is not exactly $A$, but it is equivalent to $A$. (This is the reason for asking for the reduced representation of $B\cdot B$, which is shown to be $A$.) So *as classes* we have the expected relation $B\cdot B=A$.

The modulo operation is denoted in python, sage, pari, ... with `%` - so the in the line with `-D % 4` the code computes $-D$ modulo four, else the value is rejected as a discriminant.

---

*Later later EDIT:*

The above answers the question of the representative binary quadratic forms (bqf) for the listed discriminant values $-D$. This was the main (and only) question. In the comments there are still some issues related to the primes represented by the principal form $A$. Well, Theorem 1 in *loc. cit.* already said it all. Here i can only deliver some examples. (Else, theoretically, the book of Cox on the representation of primes by quadratic binary forms would be doubled here.)

So let us consider one of the values in the list, my choice is $-D=-59$. For this number the bqf $A$ is $x^2+xy+15y^2$. Let us see which are the primes represented by $A$ among the first few odd prime values. There will be a table showing the Legendre symbol of $-D$ modulo $p$, the splitting of the polynomial $$f_{-D}=x^3+2x+1$$
considered in $\Bbb F_p[x]$, and the representations of $p$ by $A$, if any. To do the same for some other prime, please use the same code.

D = 59
A = BinaryQF_reduced_representatives(-D, primitive_only=True)[0]

count = 0
count_rep = 0

for p in primes(3, 100):
count += 1

```
F = GF(p)    # F is the field with p elements
R.<x> = PolynomialRing(F)
f = x^3 + 2*x + 1 

rep = A.solve_integer(p)
if rep:
    # we have a representation of p by A
    count_rep += 1
else:
    rep = ''    # so we will not print a None, but an empty string
sign = legendre_symbol(-D, p)
print(f"{p} & {sign} & {p % D} & {rep} & {latex(f.factor())} \\\\\\hline")
```

print("{} primes have a representation among the first {}"
.format(count_rep, count))

This gives a result, that can be inserted into an array latex environment...

$$
\begin{array}{|r||r|c|l|l|}
\hline
p & \left(\frac{-D}p\right) & p\mod D & \text{rep.} & f_{-D}=x^3+2x+1\in\Bbb F_p[x]\\\hline\hline
3 & 1 & 3 &  & (x^{3} + 2 x + 1) \\\hline
5 & 1 & 5 &  & (x^{3} + 2 x + 1) \\\hline
7 & 1 & 7 &  & (x^{3} + 2 x + 1) \\\hline
11 & -1 & 11 &  & (x + 2) \cdot (x^{2} + 9 x + 6) \\\hline
13 & -1 & 13 &  & (x + 11) \cdot (x^{2} + 2 x + 6) \\\hline
17 & 1 & 17 & (1, 1) & (x + 8) \cdot (x + 12) \cdot (x + 14) \\\hline
19 & 1 & 19 &  & (x^{3} + 2 x + 1) \\\hline
23 & -1 & 23 &  & (x + 15) \cdot (x^{2} + 8 x + 20) \\\hline
29 & 1 & 29 &  & (x^{3} + 2 x + 1) \\\hline
31 & -1 & 31 &  & (x + 8) \cdot (x^{2} + 23 x + 4) \\\hline
37 & -1 & 37 &  & (x + 15) \cdot (x^{2} + 22 x + 5) \\\hline
41 & 1 & 41 &  & (x^{3} + 2 x + 1) \\\hline
43 & -1 & 43 &  & (x + 23) \cdot (x^{2} + 20 x + 15) \\\hline
47 & -1 & 47 &  & (x + 33) \cdot (x^{2} + 14 x + 10) \\\hline
53 & 1 & 53 &  & (x^{3} + 2 x + 1) \\\hline
59 & 0 & 0 & (-1, 2) & (x + 28) \cdot (x + 45)^{2} \\\hline
61 & -1 & 2 &  & (x + 35) \cdot (x^{2} + 26 x + 7) \\\hline
67 & -1 & 8 &  & (x + 5) \cdot (x^{2} + 62 x + 27) \\\hline
71 & 1 & 12 & (7, 1) & (x + 4) \cdot (x + 23) \cdot (x + 44) \\\hline
73 & -1 & 14 &  & (x + 69) \cdot (x^{2} + 4 x + 18) \\\hline
79 & 1 & 20 &  & (x^{3} + 2 x + 1) \\\hline
83 & -1 & 24 &  & (x + 47) \cdot (x^{2} + 36 x + 53) \\\hline
89 & -1 & 30 &  & (x + 7) \cdot (x^{2} + 82 x + 51) \\\hline
97 & -1 & 38 &  & (x + 24) \cdot (x^{2} + 73 x + 93) \\\hline
101 & -1 & 42 &  & (x + 13) \cdot (x^{2} + 88 x + 70) \\\hline
103 & -1 & 44 &  & (x + 12) \cdot (x^{2} + 91 x + 43) \\\hline
107 & 1 & 48 &  & (x^{3} + 2 x + 1) \\\hline
109 & -1 & 50 &  & (x + 74) \cdot (x^{2} + 35 x + 28) \\\hline
113 & -1 & 54 &  & (x + 49) \cdot (x^{2} + 64 x + 30) \\\hline
127 & 1 & 9 &  & (x^{3} + 2 x + 1) \\\hline
131 & -1 & 13 &  & (x + 116) \cdot (x^{2} + 15 x + 96) \\\hline
137 & 1 & 19 &  & (x^{3} + 2 x + 1) \\\hline
139 & 1 & 21 & (1, 3) & (x + 40) \cdot (x + 112) \cdot (x + 126) \\\hline
149 & -1 & 31 &  & (x + 84) \cdot (x^{2} + 65 x + 55) \\\hline
151 & -1 & 33 &  & (x + 90) \cdot (x^{2} + 61 x + 99) \\\hline
157 & -1 & 39 &  & (x + 81) \cdot (x^{2} + 76 x + 126) \\\hline
163 & 1 & 45 & (4, 3) & (x + 14) \cdot (x + 53) \cdot (x + 96) \\\hline
167 & 1 & 49 &  & (x^{3} + 2 x + 1) \\\hline
173 & -1 & 55 &  & (x + 84) \cdot (x^{2} + 89 x + 138) \\\hline
179 & -1 & 2 &  & (x + 172) \cdot (x^{2} + 7 x + 51) \\\hline
181 & 1 & 4 &  & (x^{3} + 2 x + 1) \\\hline
191 & -1 & 14 &  & (x + 162) \cdot (x^{2} + 29 x + 79) \\\hline
193 & 1 & 16 &  & (x^{3} + 2 x + 1) \\\hline
197 & 1 & 20 & (13, 1) & (x + 58) \cdot (x + 162) \cdot (x + 174) \\\hline
199 & 1 & 22 &  & (x^{3} + 2 x + 1) \\\hline
\end{array}
$$
And we have a representation of the prime $p$ exactly in the cases where the second columns shows the $1$, and the last column shows three factors, so the "degree" type of the decomposition is $1+1+1$. The last column has the "degree type" $1+2$ iff there is a $-1$ in the Legendre symbol column. And the other cases correspond to Legendre symbol $=+1$, and a "degree type" $3$ in the last column. There is no "simple rule" as in the case of class number two, where the corresponding polynomial $f_{-D}$ has degree two, so that the splitting decision is in essence quadratic reciprocity. Above, for instance, there are two primes with the same rest mod $59$, namely $p=79$ and $p=197$, and $-D$ is a square modulo both $p$ values, but the representation problem shows different outcomes.

Cebotarev density arguments show that "statistically":

- we have a splitting type $1+1+1$ in $1/6$ of the cases,
- we have a splitting type $1+2$ in $1/2$ of the cases,
- we have a splitting type $3$ in $1/3$ of the cases.

To conclude, the "open issue" from the comments is covered by Theorem 1 in *loc. cit.*.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful post, kindly answer following questions: 1. Why`Is B*B == A? False`? I mean it is supposed to be TRUE instead of FALSE.    2. What is the meaning of the line `if -D % 4 in [2, 3]:` ? 3. plz suggest how I find the type of prime that are expressible in these forms $A, B, C$, for example, prime of the form $20n + 3$ or $20n +7$ are expressible as  $ A = x^2 + 5y^2$ in my INTRODUCTION.

Comment: dan, this is lovely. I did the screen capture poorly, but you put actual Latex and I  simply copied that. Meanwhile, for discriminants divisible by a square, there are rules for having $h(-w)$  and calulating $h(-wp^2).$  Odd $p$ is Theorem 7.4 on page 117 of Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. Then $p=2$ is Theorem 7.5 on page 118. Since $3$ is prime and the mechanism multiplies $h(-w)$  by a calculated factor, part of the list is the class number $1$ discriminants  with a multiplication by three.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. The first query is resolved, but Second one needs a bit elaboration. I assume, if `-D % 4 in [2, 3]:` means D is taking value from array which has 2 and 3, **but why?**  could you plz elaborate that line. About my third question, is there some kind of coding in CAS , so I can tell which type of prime represents which class, for example look at this answer: math.stackexchange.com/a/3820241/613063

Comment: Hi, could you revisit my questions,at-least regarding the code the code , Why is D taking value from array which has 2 and 3?

Comment: The function `BinaryQF_reduced_representatives` used in the code in the line with `BQFRR = BinaryQF_reduced_representatives(-D, primitive_only=True)` expects as first argument, here `-D` a "discriminant", so its value modulo four coded as `-D % 4` should not be in the list `[2, 3]`. Asking for instance for `BinaryQF_reduced_representatives(-10)` leads to an error, `ValueError: -10 is not a discriminant`. To avoid this, such values were excluded in advance. For the second question, whether some prime is represented by the binary form $A$ for each row of the table, i'll try to insert some code.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Mathematica function that returns all reduced forms of a given discriminant:

```
reducedForms[d] := 
 Module[{}, 
  Select[Flatten[
            Table[{a, b, (b^2 - d)/(4 a)}, 
                  {a, 1, Floor[Sqrt[-d/3]]}, 
                  {b, Select[Range[-a + 1, a], Mod[#^2 - d, 4 a] == 0 &]}]
         , 1], 
      GCD[Sequence@@#] == 1 && 
      #[[1]] <= #[[3]] && 
      (#[[2]] >= 0 || 4 #[[1]]^2 < #[[2]]^2 - d) &
   ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a copy of part of the list for Class number one here. If discriminant $\Delta = -D$  with positive integer $D,$ when $D \equiv 3 \pmod 8$  we have
$\Delta \equiv 5 \pmod 8$ and $$h(4 \Delta) = = 3 h(\Delta) $$ So

$$h(-44) = 3 h(-11) \; , \; \;$$

$$h(-76) = 3 h(-19) \; , \; \;$$
$$h(-108) = 3 h(-27) \; , \; \;$$
$$h(-172) = 3 h(-43) \; , \; \;$$
$$h(-268) = 3 h(-67) \; , \; \;$$
$$h(-652) = 3 h(-163) \; , \; \;$$

In Buell's Theorem 7.4, when $\Delta < -4,$   we take $s=1.$  Furthermore, page 113, we get $\chi_\Delta(p) = 0$  when $\Delta \equiv 0 \pmod p,$  otherwise
$\chi_\Delta(p) = (\Delta|p)$ is the Jacobi symbol.

Thus, when $\Delta < -4$  and
$\Delta \equiv 0 \pmod p,$
we get
$$h( \Delta p^2) =   h(\Delta) p \; . \; $$

When $\Delta < -4$  and
$\Delta \neq 0 \pmod p,$
we get
$$h( \Delta p^2) = h(\Delta) \left( p - (\Delta|p) \right)  \; . \; $$

In particular,

$$ \color{red}{ h(-243) = 3 h(-27) \; . \; \; }$$

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Code to obtain list for class number $2$:

```
for D in [1..1000]:
    if -D % 4 in [2, 3]:
        continue
    BQFRR = BinaryQF_reduced_representatives(-D, primitive_only=True)
    if len(BQFRR) != 2:
        continue
    A, B= BQFRR
    print(f"{-D} & {latex(A)} & {latex(B)} \\\\\\hline")
```

$$
\begin{array}{|r||c|c|}
\hline
-D & A & B \\\hline\hline
-15 & x^{2} + x y + 4 y^{2} & 2 x^{2} + x y + 2 y^{2} \\\hline
-20 & x^{2} + 5 y^{2} & 2 x^{2} + 2 x y + 3 y^{2} \\\hline
-24 & x^{2} + 6 y^{2} & 2 x^{2} + 3 y^{2} \\\hline
-32 & x^{2} + 8 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} + 2 x y + 3 y^{2} \\\hline
-35 & x^{2} + x y + 9 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} + x y + 3 y^{2} \\\hline
-36 & x^{2} + 9 y^{2} & 2 x^{2} + 2 x y + 5 y^{2} \\\hline
-40 & x^{2} + 10 y^{2} & 2 x^{2} + 5 y^{2} \\\hline
-48 & x^{2} + 12 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} + 4 y^{2} \\\hline
-51 & x^{2} + x y + 13 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} + 3 x y + 5 y^{2} \\\hline
-52 & x^{2} + 13 y^{2} & 2 x^{2} + 2 x y + 7 y^{2} \\\hline
-60 & x^{2} + 15 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} + 5 y^{2} \\\hline
-64 & x^{2} + 16 y^{2} & 4 x^{2} + 4 x y + 5 y^{2} \\\hline
-72 & x^{2} + 18 y^{2} & 2 x^{2} + 9 y^{2} \\\hline
-75 & x^{2} + x y + 19 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} + 3 x y + 7 y^{2} \\\hline
-88 & x^{2} + 22 y^{2} & 2 x^{2} + 11 y^{2} \\\hline
-91 & x^{2} + x y + 23 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} + 3 x y + 5 y^{2} \\\hline
-99 & x^{2} + x y + 25 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} + x y + 5 y^{2} \\\hline
-100 & x^{2} + 25 y^{2} & 2 x^{2} + 2 x y + 13 y^{2} \\\hline
-112 & x^{2} + 28 y^{2} & 4 x^{2} + 7 y^{2} \\\hline
-115 & x^{2} + x y + 29 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} + 5 x y + 7 y^{2} \\\hline
-123 & x^{2} + x y + 31 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} + 3 x y + 11 y^{2} \\\hline
-147 & x^{2} + x y + 37 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} + 3 x y + 13 y^{2} \\\hline
-148 & x^{2} + 37 y^{2} & 2 x^{2} + 2 x y + 19 y^{2} \\\hline
-187 & x^{2} + x y + 47 y^{2} & 7 x^{2} + 3 x y + 7 y^{2} \\\hline
-232 & x^{2} + 58 y^{2} & 2 x^{2} + 29 y^{2} \\\hline
-235 & x^{2} + x y + 59 y^{2} & 5 x^{2} + 5 x y + 13 y^{2} \\\hline
-267 & x^{2} + x y + 67 y^{2} & 3 x^{2} + 3 x y + 23 y^{2} \\\hline
-403 & x^{2} + x y + 101 y^{2} & 11 x^{2} + 9 x y + 11 y^{2} \\\hline
-427 & x^{2} + x y + 107 y^{2} & 7 x^{2} + 7 x y + 17 y^{2} \\\hline
\end{array}
$$